# Speech recognition engine times out when loading grammar (Microsoft.Speech)

Tags: .net, speech-recognition, speech, microsoft-speech-platform

I'm working with `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition` and need to use quite large grammars for a recognition task. So I create and later modify a grammar as a `SrgsDocument` and then construct a `Grammar` object from that. At that point, I load the grammar into the engine to prepare for recognition using the `SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar` method.

In other words I have something like:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
SrgsDocument gramDoc = new SrgsDocument();
//...modify the SrgsDocument (add rules, etc.)
Grammar gram = new Grammar(gramDoc);
sre.LoadGrammar(gram);
```

And at this point, loading the grammar, after a few minutes I sometimes (not always, and not really as a function of grammar size) get the error "A task could not complete because the SR engine had timed out."

If I catch the exception and try to load the same grammar into the same engine again, sometimes it loads successfully (though very slowly), and sometimes it gives the same error again.

What's causing this? Why would it sometimes time out and sometimes work with the same grammar/engine?

And is there something I can do to make the grammar load faster, period?

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> What's causing this?

Grammar is too large.

> Why would it sometimes time out and sometimes work with the same grammar/engine?

Sometimes it is smaller.

> And is there something I can do to make the grammar load faster, period?

I presume you compile the gramar with [Grammar Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362855%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You can use smaller grammar. You actually shouldn't use grammars of very big size, it degrades recognition accuracy because hand-constucted grammar usually fails to capture all the language dependencies.

If your language contains many choices or complex sentences it's better to simplify the grammar by making it more flexible. Instead of organizing the tree of choices you can split the chunks and present them as a separate choices. For example, if you consider grammar like

```
<result> = <day> <month> <year> <digit> |
            <year> <month> <digit> |
            <digit> <year> <month>
```

trying to capture different orders, it's better to give more flexibility

```
<result> = ( <day> | <month> | <year> | <digit> )*
```

but simplify dependencies.

A good alternative is a statistical language model in ARPA format. Once you collect sample prompts you can just create an ARPA model which will give you way better results than hand-constructed grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and suggestions. I actually haven't been compiling with Grammar Tools as you suggest, so I will look into that, but the grammar needs to be modified several times within the program so I would have to compile each new version of the grammar (would that still be faster than however Grammar()/LoadGrammar() compiles it?). And I don't quite understand what you mean by "Sometimes it is smaller"... As I said, the grammar is exactly the same. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You didn't say the grammar is the same, you said "not always, and not really as a function of grammar size" which means you tried different grammars.

Comment: In different iterations, I used different grammars, and observed that sometimes slightly larger grammars would load successfully while slightly smaller grammars would time out the engine. However, as I said: "If I catch the exception and try to load the _same grammar_ into the same engine again, _sometimes it loads successfully_ (though very slowly), and sometimes it gives the same error again."

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Can you build an ARPA model for the Microsoft.Speech.Recognition engine?  I'm pretty sure that engine doesn't support dictation at all.

Comment: @EricBrown. Hi Eric, I might be wrong but you can compile ARPA into CFG with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378460(v=office.14).aspx and load into engine. There is no support for dictation in Microsoft.Speech.Recognition in sense there is no generic preecompiled dictation grammar but you still can load your APRA models. Actually, n-gram model is equivalent to a special finite state grammar and internally in any engine they are converted to a finite state grammar anyway. So there should be no difference.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev it is good to know that one can load a custom language model this way. For my situation the language model doesn't come into play, because I'm using the recognizer for something it's not built for: essentially phone decoding for utterances in a different language. But I'm sure this will be useful info for others trying to overcome the lack of dictation support in Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.

Comment: Decoding in a different language is not a good idea for sure, you should have start with it, not with timeout issue. You probably should use more flexible recognizer like CMUSphinx which allows you to add other languages than with microsoft's one.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm doing it this way on purpose, to research the use of high-accuracy recognizers in one language for simple recognition tasks in another language, when data to train models for the second language is not available. I didn't mention it because my question here is purely about the timeouts, and why they were occurring sporadically, not about how one can best do recognition in a different language.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of other possibilities:

1. Split the grammar into multiple independent portions & load each portion into its own `Grammar` object.  (Especially handy when you have static subtrees).
2. Merge subtrees using rules & rulerefs.

Unfortunately, I don't believe that Microsoft.Speech.Recognition supports SrgsSubset items, which are very handy for building dynamic grammars.

To amplify @NikolayShmyrev 's answer - it's often better to simplify the grammar and trust the user not to say awkward phrases that are admissible but unlikely.   You can always reject those phrases during the interpretation phrase anyway.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I think something like this is what I'll have to do. Just to clarify regarding #1: you mean the combined loading time of, say, 3 shorter (but still long) grammars would be less than the loading time of one very long grammar? (Sorry if that's a stupid question.)

Comment: @pilikia The *combined* loading time will probably be the same; but the timeout is for *each* grammar.  In the worst case, you can use `LoadGrammarAsync` so that you can start loading part N after part N-1 finishes.